# KeyedCollection Remove() issue

Tags: c#

I am trying to move items between two `KeyedCollection`:

```
KeyedCollection<string, Operation> Temporary;
Temporary = LoadedConfig;
foreach (var testOp in Temporary.ToList())
{
    if (!PerformTestOpListBox.Items.Contains(testOp.Name))
    {
        Temporary.Remove(testOp.Name);
    }
}
StagingConfig = Temporary;
```

By doing so it will supposed to remove the item in `Temporary` if the ListBox does not contain such item, but somehow I found out it will also removed the same item in `LoadedConfig` as well. How could that even happened? Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: You're not making a copy of LoadedConfig, you only get a new reference to it which you stored in Temporary. Both vars point to the same KeyedCollection instance.

Comment: @rene so I should use `CopyTo(T[], Int32)`?

Comment: Yeah, if that works for you. There are no Clone or useful constructors to quickly make a copy so you are on your own.

Comment: @rene I wanted to use `Add(testOp)` at first... and I realized it would just throw me an `NullReferenceException` because `StagingConfig` was `null` (Of course it will be null because I wanted it to be empty at the first place)

Comment: Massive difference between a null collection and an empty collection

Comment: @CaiusJard Wait, then how to create an empty collection?

Comment: Depends on the kind of the collection. `new string[0]` is an empty array, `new List<string>()` is a new list, `Enumerable.Empty<string>()` is a helper method that creates an empty sequence of strings.. (And really you're supposed to use `Array.Empty<string>` not `new string[0]` if you want an empty array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your StagingConfig is null. Let's make a class that derives from KeyedCollection so you can set it to something that isn't null, then fill it:

```
public class OperationKeyedCollection : KeyedCollection<string, Operation>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(Operation item) => item.Name;
}
```

Then you can make an instance:

```
StagingConfig = new OperationKeyedCollection();
```

And, let's worst case: you're iterating a million items in a config dictionary and only adding them if they're present in a list of 10 items. It's going to be better to just use the list of 10 as the driving source because the keyed collection can look up those list items in its dictionary really quickly. If we enumerate a million items, looking them up in a list of 10, most of them wont be there, a fact that we will determine after we check all 10 items. This means youre getting on for 10 million comparisons. Flip that over and use the list of 10 and you're asking a dictionary "do you have" just 10 times. A dictionary can answer that question after, probably just a single check, so you're doing more like 10 checks rather than 10 million

```
foreach (var opName PerformTestOpListBox.Items)
{
    if (LoadedConfig.TryGetValue(opName, out var op))
    {
        StagingConfig.Add(op);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realized the only thing I was missing is `new OperationKeyedCollection();`, Delightful!

Comment: Yes, though note if the `PerformTestOpListBox.Items` is some kind of List, such that Contains will do something like "start at the start, and visit every item one by one, checking it it's the string being requested", it'll most likely be more efficient to turn the checking on its head. If we had a Dictionary of N items and a List of M items, we would find the intersect by doing `foreach item in list, does dictionary contain item?" not "foreach item in dictionary, does list contain item?" - list lookup is slow, dictionary lookup is fast.